# conditionally add to a listbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have literally struggled for about 8 hours today trying to get this to work and cant seem to work out where I am going wrong.

I have listbox1 and would like it to be populated with account numbers that are over 14 days old.

Column A hold the account numbers
Column J holds the date

Here is the code I am using so far that was kindly provided to me, I have been amending it all day with no success

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Dim I As Integer
    Dim maxRow As Integer

    maxRow = 100
    ListBox1.Clear
    For I = 1 To maxRow
        If (DateDiff("d", Now, Range("J" & I).Value) > 14) Then
            ListBox1.AddItem Range("A" & I)
        End If
    Next I
    End Sub
```

I have also included a link to my document so you can see if its any other coding that could be causing it  not work work.

Thank you in advance

[Click here to download my document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8ex7nstlbju6sm/tracker%20new.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: You can't add a range to a listbox like that. If you want the value of A#, then you need to specify that you want the value of the range.

Comment: I addition to what @asp8811 mentioned you might want to `Dim` all variables, use `.Value2` whenever possible, change the dates for `DateDiff` as I would assume that `Now` is greater than any value in the `J` column and **stop** distributing Excel workbooks with password protected macros. Nobody would ever allow to run foreign code on their computer without the option to review the code first. Finally, you might want to remove passwords from your VBA code. There seems to be an admin password = `test`.

Comment: I take all comments on board - Unfortunately this is all new to me so not sure what I am doing so apologies for sending them password protected, didnt even realise what I done.

Regarding your solutions, unfortunately ive no idea how to do what you have recommended.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please make sure to come back after the help you've gotten works out for you and mark the answer, we like points a lot.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim I As Long
Dim maxRow As Long

ListBox1.Clear

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    maxRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 1 To maxRow
        If IsDate(.Range("J" & I).Value) Then
            If Now() - .Range("J" & I).Value2 > 14 Then
                Reporting.ListBox1.AddItem .Range("A" & I).Value2
            End If
        End If
    Next I
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time, it really is appreciated - I ran this code, no errors popped up but nothing is listed in the listbox

Comment: What is the name of the sheet from which it should take the accounts / dates?

Comment: Sheet is called Sheet1 - I just tried this but didnt work: Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & I)

Comment: I just changed the code to reflect your sheet name. Furthermore, I adjusted the code to automatically detect the last row based on how many accounts are in column `A`.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, still not working. Would you mind checking my code, I have removed the password off the application: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8ex7nstlbju6sm/tracker%20new.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: I had a look at your file. Apparently there are not only dates in column `J` (starting with row 1). So, I added another `If` statement for you. Like this the code runs only when a value in column `J` can be recognized as a date. Then it works.

Comment: That didnt work for me either...hmmm - sorry to be a pain

Comment: Well, that has blown my mind  I downloaded it and still didnt work. I will try this on a different system tomorrow and then accept your answer once I am home. Thank you for spending so much time helping me, greatly appreciated

Comment: Thanks Ralph - listbox1 is located on the tab 3 weeks, thats the one that think remains blank for some reason. The rest working fine :)

Comment: I made three final adjustments: (1) `If IsDate(.Range("J" & I).Value) Then` instead of `If IsDate(.Range("J" & I).Value2) Then` (2) Explicit reference to the `Reporting` form. (3) Remove `DateDiff("d")` because for Excel its the same as subtracting two numbers from one another.

Comment: Ralph - That works 100%. Perfect. I can see how it works now, as its more or less new to me it was a big struggle. Thank you so much, I wish you all the best. Big thumbs up